# why does parenthesis needed for assignment in second part of conditional operator in c

Tags: c

The code below

```
i>0?j=9:i=7;
```

Is giving an error:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Can you explain this why I am getting this error?
when, `i>0?j=9:(i=7);` is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Imho: basically your problem is that is C the termary operator has higher priority than "=" (in c++ the prioriy is equal, so it works as expected) and that is the reason you need the parenthesis.

Comment: then why there is no need of parenthesis around j?